# Does the intermediate value property mean "the image of an interval is also an interval"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Wikipedia says the following thing about Darboux's theorem:

> In mathematics, Darboux's theorem is a theorem in real analysis, named after Jean Gaston Darboux. It states that every function that results from the differentiation of another function has the intermediate value property: the image of an interval is also an interval.

However for the following function:

$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2sin(\frac{1}{x})&\text{if } x \neq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } x=0,
\end{cases}
$$

$f'(x)$ satisfying the condition in the Darboux's theorem (i.e everywhere differentiable) but is discontinuous at $0$ thus not an interval?

Note: I'm aware of the answer for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454528/what-is-meant-by-the-image-of-an-interval-is-also-an-interval-when-this-phrase) which I found to be the same as the following theorem:

> Let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be connected and $f: E\to \ \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Then $f(E)$ is connected.

But the above-mentioned function says a different thing.

Comment: “discontinuous at 0, thus not an interval.” Elaborate on this

Comment: The Conway 13 function is discontinuous everywhere and has the intermediate value property. So continuity isn't required.

Comment: What interval's image under your $f'$ is not an interval?

Comment: @Andrew, cc: Robert Isreal, my misunderstanding! It should always be an interval due the definition of interval and what the Darboux theorem is about.

Comment: I made a mistake when interpreting the connection between Darboux's theorem and the definition of the interval.

Comment: If you understand the situation now, Tran, you might consider posting an answer to your own question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I've added my proof. Though I suspect it may be too lengthy.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, the discontinuous is irrelevant here and the image of an interval is indeed an interval.

Recall the Darboux's theorem:

> Let $f: I\to\mathbb{R}$ be a real-value differentiable function then $f'$ has the **intermediate value property**:
> If and $a$ and $b$ are points in $I$ with $a\lt b$, then for every $y$ between $f'(a)$ and $f'(b)$ there exists an $x$ in $[a, b]$ such that $f'(x)=y$.

We will show that the derivative of $f$ on any interval $E\subseteq I$ forms an interval. Equivalently, if $E\subseteq I$ is an interval then the set $f'(E)$ is also an interval.

The derivative of $f$ exists for every point in $I$ implies that the set $f'(E)$ is bounded thus both the infimum and supremum exist for this set. Let $u=inf(f'(E))$, $v=sup(f'(E))$, the fact that $E$ is an interval implies that $u<v$.

If $u\in f'(E)$ and $v\in f'(E)$, then the Darboux's theorem states that $\forall y: u\lt y\lt v$, there exists $x\in E: y=f'(x)$. In other words, $y\in f'(E)$ which implies that $f'(E)$ is an interval.

Next suppose $u\notin f'(E)$ and $v\in f'(E)$. Since $u=inf(f'(E))$ then $\forall y\in f'(E)$ such that $u\lt y$ there always exists $B_u\in f'(E): u\lt B_u\le y$, otherwise $y=inf(f'(E))$ which is a contradiction. But again in this case, applying the Darboux's theorem for $y$ between $[B_u, v]$ shows that there exists an $x$ such that $y=f'(x)\in f'(E)$ thus we conclude that $f'(E)$ is an interval.

The other two cases where $u\in f'(E), v\notin f'(E)$ and both $u, v \notin f'(E)$ follow similarly.